# Unable to add native .dll reference to source generator project

Tags: c#, code-generation, roslyn-code-analysis

You can find the full source code at https://github.com/myblindy/GrimBuilding/tree/efcore (the `efcore` branch).

I understand that source generators can't automatically harvest dependencies from nuget packages and you have to use a clunky work-around to get it to work, and I have done so. This is my source generator project:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <LangVersion>preview</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp" Version="4.0.0-1.final" PrivateAssets="all" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers" Version="3.3.2" PrivateAssets="all" />
    <PackageReference Include="SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_e_sqlite3" Version="2.*-*" GeneratePathProperty="true" PrivateAssets="all" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Core" Version="6.*-*" GeneratePathProperty="true" PrivateAssets="all" />
    <PackageReference Include="SQLitePCLRaw.lib.e_sqlite3" Version="2.*-*" GeneratePathProperty="true" PrivateAssets="all" />
    <PackageReference Include="SQLitePCLRaw.provider.e_sqlite3" Version="2.*-*" GeneratePathProperty="true" PrivateAssets="all" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <GetTargetPathDependsOn>$(GetTargetPathDependsOn);GetDependencyTargetPaths</GetTargetPathDependsOn>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="GetDependencyTargetPaths">
    <ItemGroup>
      <TargetPathWithTargetPlatformMoniker Include="$(PKGSQLitePCLRaw_bundle_e_sqlite3)\lib\netstandard2.0\SQLitePCLRaw.batteries_v2.dll" IncludeRuntimeDependency="false" />
      <TargetPathWithTargetPlatformMoniker Include="$(PKGSQLitePCLRaw_provider_e_sqlite3)\lib\netstandard2.0\SQLitePCLRaw.provider.e_sqlite3.dll" IncludeRuntimeDependency="false" />
      <TargetPathWithTargetPlatformMoniker Include="$(PKGSQLitePCLRaw_lib_e_sqlite3)\runtimes\win-x64\native\e_sqlite3.dll" IncludeRuntimeDependency="false" />
      <TargetPathWithTargetPlatformMoniker Include="$(PKGMicrosoft_Data_Sqlite_Core)\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.dll" IncludeRuntimeDependency="false" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Since there also isn't any transitive support, I added every nested `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite` package one by one, generated their path property and referenced it using `TargetPathWithTargetPlatformMoniker`. It all works until I get to the native `e_sqlite3.dll`, if I use `TargetPathWithTargetPlatformMoniker` with it, it tries to reference it as a managed library, and it fails as expected:

> 4>CSC : warning CS8034: Unable to load Analyzer assembly C:\Users\meep.nuget\packages\sqlitepclraw.lib.e_sqlite3\2.0.5-pre20210521085756\runtimes\win-x64\native\e_sqlite3.dll : PE image doesn't contain managed metadata.

So given that the path is found, is there a different tag I can use to make the main project copy the `e_sqlite3.dll` file so the analyzer can use it?

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [.NET project SDK overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/overview):

**Build events**

In SDK-style projects, use an MSBuild target named PreBuild or PostBuild and set the BeforeTargets property for PreBuild or the AfterTargets property for PostBuild.

```
 <Target Name="PreBuild" BeforeTargets="PreBuildEvent">
    <Exec Command="&quot;$(ProjectDir)PreBuildEvent.bat&quot; &quot;$(ProjectDir)..\&quot; &quot;$(ProjectDir)&quot; &quot;$(TargetDir)&quot;" />
</Target>

<Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent">
   <Exec Command="echo Output written to $(TargetDir)" />
</Target>
```

Maybe you can move the file manually using one of these directives?

There's also this:

```
<Content Include="$(OutputPath)\*.dll;$(OutputPath)\*.json">
      <Pack>true</Pack>
      <PackagePath>build\</PackagePath>
</Content>
```

Could you move the file like that?

Comment: unfortunately, although you can use the latter method to move the native binaries to the output directory, the actual references in code arent redirected, and they still attempt to access the dlls from some non-existent path. I think theres some magic in `TargetPathWithTargetPlatformMoniker` that rebinds all the references that isnt done with just a `Content` or `None` :(